# I am trying to print a random character from an array by using rand()

Tags: arrays, c, random

Hello all I want to write a program to randomly choose a character from an array, so far I have come up with this code. I get an *Error message help...Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)* at the last printf()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int lower = 1, upper = 6;
    int test;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    char*  placeArray[]={"Renti","Mosxato","Tavros","Kallithea","Petralona","Thisio"};
    int i, num;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
        num=(rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        test=(int)num;
        printf("%d ",num);
        printf("%s\n",placeArray[num]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://ideone.com/YjNV40). Please post your *actual* code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: this is the entire code, it is a work in progress

Comment: shoot, there is a mistake in the code that I provided..... nice in the last printf I originally had num instead of I. So sorry. can I edit the post?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the post!

Comment: placeArray[] can take only up to 5 as index. C array indexes start at 0.

Comment: great, thank you  I found it, now it is the correct wrong code! thanks.

Comment: @SparKot so what should I do?

Comment: @SparKot I found it I just change the 6 to a 5 in the for loop, it really was kinda like a stack overflow... or not. Anyway thank you so much!!!

Comment: You don't really need `lower/upper` and using `1` just makes the code problematic. Also, no need to hardwire with `6` either. A simpler way: `num = rand() % (sizeof(placeArray) / sizeof(placeArray[0])); printf("%d %s\n",num,placeArray[num]);`

Comment: GEORGE MPOUK,Is the goal to print a random _string_ from the list "Renti","Mosxato","Tavros","Kallithea","Petralona","Thisio" **or** to print a  random _character_ from one of those words?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the goal is to print random strings from the list

Comment: @GEORGEMPOUK Consider changing the title to match your goal.

Answer (score 2):

`num` should be `num-1` in the last `printf`, because the range of the elements in the array is 0 to 5, as shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int lower = 1, upper = 6;
    int test;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    char * placeArray[]= {"Renti", "Mosxato", "Tavros", "Kallithea", "Petralona", "Thisio"};
    int i, num;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        test = (int)num;
        printf("%d ", num);
        printf("%s\n", placeArray[num - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```